# JVM thread management v.s. OS scheduling

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, jvm, quasar

As I know, one of the most common JVM concurrency API: futures - at least as implemented in scala - rely on user code to relinquish a thread when it is potentially going to be waiting idle. In scala it's commonly referred to as "avoiding blocking", and the developer has to implement it everywhere it makes sense. 
Not quite efficient.

Is there something very entirely inherent to the JVM, that prevents the JVM switching the context of a thread to new tasks - when the thread is idle - as implemented by operating system process schedulers?

Comment: More concisely, "Does the JVM use user-mode threads?"? (Switching tasks when something is blocked is *exactly what threads do*)

Comment: Albeit some overlap, those are not the same question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something very entirely inherent to the JVM, that prevents the JVM switching the context of a thread to new tasks - when the thread is idle - as implemented by operating system process schedulers?

Mostly the need that such switch has to be done cooperatively. Every single blocking method must be wrapped or re-implemented in a way that allows the task to be resumed once it is done, after all, there is no native thread waiting for completion of the blocking action anymore.

While this can be done in principle for JVM-internal blocking methods, consider arbitrary native code executed via JNI, the JVM wouldn't know how to stack-switch those native threads, they're stuck in native code after all.

You might want to have a look at [quasar](http://www.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/), as I understand it they implemented such wrappers or equivalents for some JDK-internal methods, such as `sleep`, `park`/`unpark`, channel-based-IO and a bunch of others which allows their fibers (and thus futures running on those fibers) to perform exactly that kind of user-mode context switching while they wait for completion.

Edit: JNI alone already is *sufficient* to limit user-mode task switching to being an opportunistic optimization that may have to fall back to spinning up additional native threads when native code blocks a thread.

But it is not the only issue, for example on linux truly asynchronous file IO operations need filesystem and kernel support (see this [SO question on AIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768083/difference-between-posix-aio-and-libaio-on-linux)), which not all of them provide. Where it is not provided it has to be emulated using additional blocking IO threads, thus re-introducing all the overhead we wanted to avoid in the first place. Might as well just block on the thread pool itself and spin up additional threads, at least we'll avoid inter-thread-communication that way.

Memory-mapped files can also block a thread and force the OS-scheduler to suspend the thread due to page faults and I'm not aware of means to cooperate with the virtual memory system to avoid that.

Not to mention that *all* blocking calls on the VM would have to re-implemented using asynchronous equivalents provided by the OS. Miss even one and you'll have a blocked thread. If you have a blocked thread your thread pools will need an auto-grow feature and we're back to square one.

Last but not least, there may be cases where blocking, one-thread-per-filedescriptor IO may be desirable. The pervasive changes required to guarantee user-mode switching might break those.

So all in all, user mode switching is possible, *sometimes*. But the JVM cannot make hard guarantees about it so it has to implement all the native thread handling anyway and the programmer will have code at least somewhat cooperatively with the assumptions of the thread pools executing those futures in mind. Some of the cases could be eliminated, but not all of them.

Comment: Thanks! oddly enough I stumbled on Quasar a year ago, and it seemed "beta" stuff then, no production implementations. But on the overall, does the problematic aspect generalize outside of something rather esoteric like JNI? could you further clarify/generalize what is it in JVM architecture that prevents preemptive scheduling in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, how sad that multitasking doesn't work in the JVM as it does in the OS ;(

Comment: The problem is simply that the JVM (currently) uses kernel threads to implement Java threads, and those have quite a high overhead. I should note, however, that *occasionally* blocking kernel threads is perfectly fine, so stuff like virtual memory paging should not hurt you at all. As the main author of Quasar I can tell you that Quasar is certainly production ready (and used in production).