# "Linux aio" and "Linux native aio" are the same thing?

Tags: linux, model, kernel, aio

I'm recently digging into linux io model, and I frequently hear that like windows IOCP, linux has its own aio model implementation: Glibc aio and kernel aio.

Question:

(1) when people say "linux native aio", which model is indicated?

(2) I hear 2 different terms, "linux aio" and "linux native aio". Are they the same thing, or indicating different implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Linux native AIO** is **kernel AIO**.  The interfaces are `io_setup(2), io_submit(2), io_getevents(2),` and a handful of other calls.

When people are talking about "linux AIO", they probably mean "Linux native AIO" - though who knows.  This is the Internet, after all.

Posix AIO is something altogether different.  It's implemented with threading in user-space.  See the top answer to [Difference between POSIX AIO and libaio on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768083/difference-between-posix-aio-and-libaio-on-linux) for a good, well vetted description of the differences between Posix AIO and Linux kernel AIO.