# fio error checking for write operations

Tags: c, io, linux-kernel, aio

I am trying to determine how fio (github.com/axboe/fio) determines if there is a write error when using the libaio ioengine.

From the post at [linux kernel aio functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918530/linux-kernel-aio-functionality), I see an example of error checking in the callback function, work_done(), which examines the events returned by io_getevents().

But I cannot find any similar error checking in the fio_libaio_getevents() function from libaio.c (https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/engines/libaio.c#L145).

I have written to the mailing list (fio@vger.kernel.org) from https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/fio-2.17/README#L77, but the mail bounces.  So any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that call from user space or kernel space?

Answer (score 1):

The errors are returned as `res` and `res2` in `struct iocb`.  In that fio code, you can see the iocb array passed in here, as `ld->aio_events + events`.

```
        r = io_getevents(ld->aio_ctx, actual_min,
            max, ld->aio_events + events, lt);
```

The actual error is checked earlier in the file, in the function `fio_libaio_event`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Also, the reason I had problems emailing fio@vger.kernel.org was because my email was in HTML format, and it was rejected for security reasons.